# Какое наиболее оптимальное решение задачи при поиске координат?

Tags: php

Друзья, всем привет! Нашел интересную задачу в интернете, но не понимаю, как её решить наиболее оптимально.

Условие задачи: есть ограниченная плоскость координат (x,y). Есть предмет, который стоит на месте, т.е. имеет постоянные координаты, они генерируется рандомно. Есть персонаж, которым мы управляем. Мы можем задать ему лишь путь движения, наша задача - довести его до предмета самым коротким путем. Я пошел самым простым процедурным путем и решил это таким образом:

```
/*
*@param $lightX - координата X для предмета
*@param $lightY - координата Y для предмета
*@param $initialX - координата X для героя
*@param $initialY - координата Y для героя
*
*@return string - направление движения
*/

function getDirection($lightX, $lightY, $initialX, $initialY) 
{           
    if($initialTX > $lightX && $initialTY == $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'W';
    }
    if($initialTX > $lightX && $initialTY > $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'NW';
    }
    if($initialTX > $lightX && $initialTY < $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'SW';
    }
    if($initialTX < $lightX && $initialTY == $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'E';
    }
    if($initialTX < $lightX && $initialTY > $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'NE';
    }
    if($initialTX < $lightX && $initialTY < $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'SE';
    }
    if($initialTX == $lightX && $initialTY < $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'S';
    }
    if($initialTX == $lightX && $initialTY > $lightY) {
        $moveTo = 'N';
    }
    return $moveTo;
}
```

Проблема данного подхода в том, что он предлагает не наиболее короткий путь. Т.е. он не строит прямую линию к предмету, а сначала доходит до положения, где одна из координат равна, а потом уже идет напрямую по второй координате. Какие есть варианты решения подобной задачи? Буду рад любым предложениям :)

UPD: не указал, как именно мы управляем персонажем. Мы можем дать ему 8 вариантов движения, т.е. W,E,S,N,NW,SW,NE,SE. Простыми словами, двигаться он может только по "компасу".

Также хотелось бы понять, есть ли более рациональная запись, нежели множество if'ов? Через switch с 2 операторами это не сделать

Comment: Персонаж может двигаться под любым углом или только параллельно осям? И определен ли дискрет перемещения?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov обновил условия задачи, забыл это дописать. Персонаж может двигаться только по 8 направлениям, т.е. подобие простого компаса.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov дискрет перемещения обусловлен каждой итерацией цикла, за 1 итерацию персонаж двигается на 1 позицию в указанном направлении.

Comment: В таком  случае по каждой отдельно взятой координате он движется в направлении цели. Т.е. сначала по диагонали, потом по горизонтали или вертикали. Всё собсно... Т.е. dx=sign(X-x), dy=sign(Y-y), где (X,Y) - координаты цели, а (x,y) - текущие координаты. Количество требуемых шагов MAX(abs(X-x0),abs(Y-y0)).

Comment: @Akina в этом и проблема, что это не является наиболее оптимальным путем. Тут можно задачу поставить еще одним образом: персонаж должен построить наиболее близкую линию, а не дойти до цели. Т.е. он может найти сначала X координату в плоскости, потом Y, но это будет не оптимально.

Comment: *это не является наиболее оптимальным путем* Значит, мы по-разному трактуем оптимальность. Для меня это минимизация количества шагов. К тому же при этом пройденный путь получается кратчайшим. Т.е. можно считать за оптимум минимизацию расстояния - решение не изменится. А что есть оптимальность для Вас?

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм Брезенхэма - Ваш ответ!

[Ссылка на википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Открыв увидите анимацию, которая точь в точь ваша задача, там все подробно описано с формулами и примерами.